# How to send email to "anonymous" user when a new node is created

Tags: 7, emails, notifications

I've been looking at a couple of modules and none of them seem to work the way I want to.

I'd like to display a textfield for an anonymous user to enter his email. Everytime a node of a certain type (blog post) is created, an email would be sent to every person who gave their email.

How could I achieve that in Drupal 7 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) looks like it would work perfectly for this.

> Simplenews publishes and sends newsletters to lists of subscribers. Both anonymous and authenticated users can opt-in to different mailing lists. HTML email can be sent by adding Mime Mail module.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom module. If you are showing form as a block, you can use 
hook_block_info() or hook_block_configure() hooks

Then use YOURMOUDLE_form api to create form and implement the submit handler for the form i.e YOURMODULE_form_submit() where you write insert queries

Now to send the email you can use hook_node_insert() hook to do your things after the node is inserted in the tables

Comment: use [simplenews module](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews). You wont need custom coding

Answer (score 0):

Use [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module with the following information. Create a field for that content type called email.

**Events**
After saving new content

**Conditions**
Content is of type "select your content type"

**Actions**
Send mail - and in the to section use your field token like [node:field-email] with an appropriate subject and message.

Comment: I checked rules, but did not understand how to send email to anonymous users. Any hint ?

Comment: @Ebpo checkout the videocast for rules as it is very framework and you will end up using it time and again. So take some time and run through all the videos http://nodeone.se/sv/node/32

Comment: Didn't realize it was this big! I will look for sure :) Thanks for the info.